# Attach variable InfoWindow to polyline routes in Google Maps v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a map where I have a lot of routes plotted from JSON. This works fine but I want to add some information for each route when I click on a route. I have found a Fiddle demo which already had a route so I just modified it but it illustrates my problem:

```
function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552, 76.327043),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    // Define an info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ""
    });

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // Route 1 array
    var polylineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566, 76.331549),
        [CUT]
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552, 76.327043) 
    ];

    var txt = "This is the FIRST route";

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: polylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF3300',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 5
    });

    polyline.setMap(map);

    // Add a "click" event for this route
    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function (e) {
        infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(txt);
        infowindow.open(map);
    });

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // Route 2 array
    var polylineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.014566, 76.331549),
        [CUT]
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.015552, 76.327043)
    ];

    var txt = "This is the SECOND route";

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: polylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF3300',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 5
    });

    polyline.setMap(map);

    // Add a "click" event for this route
    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function (e) {
        infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(txt);
        infowindow.open(map);
    });

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // Click anywhere on the map to close the info window
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () {
        infowindow.close();
    });

}
```

Do note that I get "This is the SECOND route" for both routes:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic]

I define each text with:

```
var txt = "This is the FIRST route";

// Add a "click" event for this route
    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function (e) {
        infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(txt);
        infowindow.open(map);
    });
```

I have this [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NUkCs/21/).

How can I get variable text for each route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you accidently reuse the variable `txt` in your code. When you have

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function (e) {
   infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
   infowindow.setContent(txt); //you accidently reuse the last txt here
   infowindow.open(map);
});
```

... it will always be the last assigned `txt` that is in use :

```js
var txt = "This is the SECOND route";
```

Just assign `txt` as a property to your PolyLine object :

```js
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  txt : txt, 
  ...
```

and access that property in the click-handler :

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function (e) {
  infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
  infowindow.setContent(this.txt); // <--- here
  infowindow.open(map);
});
```

see forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LkskL/**

Comment: I need to be quicker next time :)

Comment: I didn't know you could create your own property inside the polyline. This was just what I needed - thanks.

Comment: @JohnMalli, google maps objects are just objects like everything else in javascript. You can fill them up with whatever you want. Also other objects - your polyline could hold 1000 markers.